# Error | Getting org.springframework.dao.CannotAcquireLockException: org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not execute statement

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

> Error | Getting org.springframework.dao.CannotAcquireLockException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not execute statement

I have a code, which is updating and inserting 50 records in a batch at a time.

```
void updateAndInsert(List<UserData> userDataList) {
    for(List<UserData> userData : Lists.partition(userDataList, 50)) {
        updateRecords(userData);
        insertRecords(userData);
    }
}

updateRecords(List<UserData> userData) {
       return em.createNamedQuery("updateUserData").setParameter("userData",         userData).executeUpdate();
}

updateRecords(List<UserData> userData) {
       //  Insert in batch of 50
}
```

And also inserting 50 records at a time.

This code is working fine, when calling updateAndInsert from single thread.

But it is giving CannotAcquireLockException when calling the updateAndInsert method from multiple threads. I have the requirement to call this method for a batch from parallel. Is there any way to avoid this exception.

Can I apply wait for some time whenever got this exception and again try to insert or update in database.

I want to insert and update records in batches of 50 from multiple threads, without any exception.